# Unlock password protected BUT formatted micro sd

Tags: ubuntu, memory, passwords, sd-card, write-protect

I have a micro SD memory card. I've forgot the password so I successfully formatted it on Ubuntu.

Now I am able to open and use my card with my PC with no need of a password. But when I insert it into my phone (Nokia Asha 200), I am asked for a password. The same happens with another phone too.

**How can I access and use my card in the phones?**

**UPDATE** :

The memory card is a *Silicon Power 8GB class4* micro SD card.

I've tried using the card on these phones : Nokia Asha 200 (Java), Samsung A5 2017 (Android)

*I've tried these:*

- Formatted card with Windows (disk management, file explorer), Ubuntu (file manager, gparted) as both FAT32 and NTFS
- Recreated partition table in both Windows and Ubuntu.
- Low level format with [HDD Low Level Format Tool](http://ccm.net/download/download-815-hdd-low-level-format-tool)
- Formatting with manufacturer provided tools (HP, Silicon Power, etc) in Windows.

Comment: Try [SDFormatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/)?

Comment: @Mokubai yes but it was same as widows format. not anymore. I also tried MMC Unlocker. Just crashes after clicking `unlock`. maybe i dont know how to use it?

Comment: Is microsd password a hardware lock or just software password? I think it's independent from software,partitioning,... Am i right?

Comment: Have you tried entering as password the pin used for your lock screen?

Comment: Can you try to format it in the phone ? Or in some other phone ?

Comment: @harrymc This is EXACTLY my problem! The memory asks me for a password on every phone I tried. BUT I can read/write from/into it on PC without any password! I've formatted it many times

Comment: What model is your SD card and the phones you have tried it on?

Comment: @harrymc Silicon Power Class4 8GB MicroSD- Nokia Asha 200, Samsung A5 2017

Comment: Some Nokia phones can format any card (were mentioned E66, N8, 701 but maybe they no longer exist). Silicon Power has a [Flash Drive Recovery Software](https://www.silicon-power.com/web/download-USBrecovery) you could try.

Comment: @harrymc I tries but unfortunately this is just a simple format tool like [SDFormatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/). Just formats SD card like windows

Comment: Try to format it using [HDD Low Level Format Tool](http://ccm.net/download/download-815-hdd-low-level-format-tool) or [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=197).

Comment: @harrymc Nothing happened :( Even low level format not helped me! O God! Where is the password of this damn card stored?! I think the microSD password is stored on hardware.

Comment: @Hastur Didn't work. Thanks anyway, but we are NOT talking about default PHONE password! Card spec is included in previous comments.

Comment: Just a couple of shots in the dark. The codes `0000` or the one of your telephone, the [software from the producer page](https://www.silicon-power.com/web/software) with a special mention to [this one](https://www.silicon-power.com/web/download-SPwidget)

Comment: @AliBagheriShakib, it's time you [edit] the question updating it with useful info, instead to leave to us to search in the comments. Good Luck.

Comment: If low-level format didn't work, then your card is probably just faulty.

Comment: @harrymc It is better to read carefully the question. I can use the card with my PC(read,write) like a flash memory! I'm confused where the lock is stored?! :|

Comment: I did read it. Different operating systems may use different hardware functions. My guess is that the PC happens not to use the hardware function which makes the phone believe that there is a password when there is none. Unfortunately, SD cards are fragile and cannot really be repaired.

Comment: It might. But I will continue challenging this damn bad card to force him work! :-P Thank u @harrymc

Comment: I found some document about SD card lock: https://www.seanet.com/~karllunt/sdlocker2.html But it seems that if the SD card is locked, you should not be able to access it via the PC. So maybe this is another form of lock.

Comment: You might try [this utility](http://www.flashdrive-repair.com/2013/06/download-silicon-power-formatter-v-37.html) to update the firmware of the SD card. Read carefully the instructions for verifying the chip vendor.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what I said in the comments above :

If an SD flash card goes bad, one might do the following, in ascending order of
desperation:

- Reformat the card as FAT32 on a computer (a phone would be even better -
  were especially mentioned the old Nokia E66, N8, 701
  or Symbian phone using FExplorer)
- Do low-level format on a computer using a utility such as
  [HDD Low Level Format Tool](http://ccm.net/download/download-815-hdd-low-level-format-tool)
- For Silicon Power, one might use the
  [Silicon Power Formatter](http://www.flashdrive-repair.com/2013/06/download-silicon-power-formatter-v-37.html)
  which can repair the card's firmware.
  Read carefully the instructions for verifying the chip vendor of the card.
- Get a new card - your data will be safer this way.
  Unfortunately, SD cards are fragile and cannot easily be repaired.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70443/discussion-on-answer-by-harrymc-unlock-password-protected-but-formatted-micro-sd).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the password remover software provided by Silicon Power themself?

It only seems to work on Windows 7 though.

You can find the download here: https://www.silicon-power.com/web/download-USBwin7

Comment: I tried in windows 10 64 bit, the program runs but says: No Device found

Answer (score 0):

> Go to the file manager on your mobile phone. Then, head to Settings >
> System Folders. Find a file called *mmcstore*, and send it to your
> computer using Bluetooth. Next, use Notepad to open your file. The
> password for your memory card is located within that file.
>
> Another possible method includes you inserting your card into your
> phone without accessing it. Run FExplorer, and open the C:\system file
> path. Find the file called *mmcstore*, and rename it as mmcstore.txt.
> Copy the .txt file to your PC, and open it in Notepad. Your password will be located within that file.

http://ccm.net/faq/4154-lost-password-to-microsd-card

Or try this method involving remote locking of phone to force MMC password reset:
https://nokia3110c.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/remove-password-from-microsd-card-for-nokia-3110c-or-s40-phones/

Failing that try Nemesis Service Suite and a data cable:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-T4tWrUIBg

Comment: this'll work only when if you set card password just on the phone you try to fetch `mmcstore` file! And the phone not reset yet after set password! What if your phone reset to factory setting and worst than it, the phone is Java Series40?!

Comment: so if you've formatted the card, where is the password stored if not on the phone?

Comment: password stored on the phone JUST to make it easy for the user(not force him to enter password every minute). The password stored on card too. So when u inserted card into another phone or you reset phone, you'll asked for password. Confusing problem is why there is password, while I formatted card and even able to read/write into it with PC!

Comment: I think the phone is caching the password with some identifier that relates it to the card so it asks you even after you format. I advise to delete the mmcstore from your phone if possible, or reset the password (you'll be able to view it in the mmcstore) on the card and remove it the correct way from the phone. You need to remove the stored password from both the phone and the card.

Comment: there is no `mmcstore` when your phone is Java series 40! your offered solution is applicable on a Symbian phone. FExplorer is not made for ancient Java phones :D

Comment: OK, in that case you can try this method involving remote locking of phone to force MMC password reset: https://nokia3110c.wordpress.com/2010/03/05/remove-password-from-microsd-card-for-nokia-3110c-or-s40-phones/

Comment: or try Nemesis Service Suite with a data cable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-T4tWrUIBg

Comment: Matt it would be wise to add those solutions to the original one as your comments have fallen below displaying threshold into 'click here to display' space.

Answer (score 0):

If literally nothing else is working, you might want to connect the SD card to your PC and try this command once:

```
format <drive_letter>: /fs:NTFS /p:1
```

This should write zeroes to every sector of your card and clear all data out.

(See https://www.lifewire.com/use-the-format-command-to-write-zeros-to-a-hard-drive-2626162)

Comment: not worked. tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this card in your phone(s), as they're caching the password based on the low level card identifier.

Formatting the card only removes the stored password on the card, but it's still on the phone and the phone will continue to look for it on the card. If it's happening on multiple phones you'd previously put the card in then they will be caching the password also.

I recommend using a different memory card if you're not able to remove the cached passwords on the phone(s).

Comment: This card was only used by one phone(Asha200). I tried on other phones which never used in them but they have been asked for password too. I think formatting card would not help to remove probably its HW password

Comment: In this case the password must still be stored on the card, somehow, somewhere. Did you try repartitioning the card? After that do an overwrite format.

Comment: Yes, i tried everything you think(except formatting card with a Nokia E Series phone, cause I have not anyone) But this damn card is tooooooo headstrong! :/